# WinRM keeps giving me firewall error message

Tags: windows-10, remote

I'm trying to enable the remote management on my Windows 10 machine but when I run the command:

> winrm quickconfig

It keeps giving me a firewall error and, although I already did it, it keeps saying to change the network connection type to private.
This is the complete output:

```
PS C:\Users\aless> winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WSManFault
    Message
        ProviderFault
            WSManFault
                Message = WinRM firewall exception will not work since one of the network connection types on this machine is set to Public. Change the network connection type to either Domain or Private and try again.

Error number:  -2144108183 0x80338169
WinRM firewall exception will not work since one of the network connection types on this machine is set to Public. Change the network connection type to either Domain or Private and try again.
```

This machine is running a clean windows 10 installation and I enabled on it Hyper-V.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? I see the same issue. My network is also private

Comment: Nope, I gave up..